# Need help to fix mac partition with APFS

Tags: macos, partition, recovery, apfs, diskutil

For some unknown reason, the controller for my USB drive failed and now I'm unable to access the drive. I've tried to do something with `gpt`, but I guess I only screwed it up.

Could someone help me to recover the APFS? I assume I need to remove and add entries.

Here is the data output:

```
diskutil list

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                                                   *5.0 TB     disk2
```

```
sudo gpt -r show disk2
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34  9767541101         
  9767541135          32         Sec GPT table
  9767541167           1         Sec GPT header
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Was this a controller in an external drive? Many external drives use a special type of formatting which hides the real block size from the OS - effectively making it unusable if you remove the drive from the enclosure. I don't have any kind of list as to who does this, but maybe the make & model may help.

Comment: Yes, you're right @Tetsujin. I removed it from the case and put it into another case to access the data. It was the an "Western Digital 5TB Elements Desktop" case.The data seems to be still on the HDD by checking with Easeus Recovery Software.

Comment: I think WD Elements is one that does this 'trick'. See what EaseUS can find, but don't be surprised if it *thinks* it can find data which turns out to be junk once recovered. It *may* be able to read around this 'fake' formatting but I'm not certain. Test your recovery, try different recovery apps. Once happy, you can just reformat the drive & it should just work again.

Comment: There is tons of data on it and it will lose the whole folder structure etc. That's why I want to kind of recreate the APFS container.

Comment: idk how to do that, sorry, short of putting it in another WD enclosure.